# Atom Editor highlight parentheses if inside

Tags: settings, highlight, atom-editor

Is there a setting somewhere in Atom, to make it highlight innermost parentheses and brackets and braces and whatever else, no matter where inside the cursor is, not just when the cursor is next one of the characters enclosing the?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this setting does not exist. The code that matches brackets is found in the package [bracket-matcher](https://github.com/atom/bracket-matcher).

**Bracket-Matcher:**

> Highlights and jumps between [], (), and {}. Also highlights matching XML and HTML tags.

If you want to implement this functionality I suggest writing a new package (or modifying the above one, since most of the work will be done for you) that will do what you desire.
Bracket-matcher already knows whether or now it's inside a pair of brackets (since it says `Use` <kbd>ctrl-cmd-m</kbd> `to select all the text inside the current brackets`)  so I would suggest looking into that part of the plugin.

Comment: I have no experience in writing plugins for atom, so I guess I'd have to get knowledgeable about that first, making it a project for another time. There is so much one should learn …